# nginx reverse proxy https to http

Tags: nginx, ssl, web-server, reverse-proxy, https

I have a Linux server, on which I created a public web app (as a test) accessible here: http://tropo.gps.caltech.edu:9384/jsserve

It works as intended. As you can see, it is served on port 9384 with http protocol.

However, I would like to have this public web app accessible via https. I do have SSL certificate, but I want to use another port than 443.

Here is my nginx configuration file: (the relevant bits)

```
server {
    listen 44301 ssl; 

    ssl_certificate [...];
    ssl_certificate_key [...];

    server_name tropo.gps.caltech.edu;

    location /jsserve {
        proxy_pass http://tropo.gps.caltech.edu:9384;
    }
}
```

It seems that I am doing something wrong, as I generate this: https://tropo.gps.caltech.edu:44301/jsserve , https is crossed in red and "not secured" warning appears.
Moreover, my web apps is not working (a slider appear, it can be moved, but there is no response).

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: `tropo.gps.caltech.edu:44301 uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.` - looks like you don't understand the warning, your self signed certificate isn't trusted, but you can trust it if you want

Comment: You're right, I changed the settings in my browser for https://tropo.gps.caltech.edu:44301/jsserve (allow insecure content) and it worked. The problem is that mixed content, due to my invalid security certificate I imagine. Thanks for pointing this.

Comment: `The problem is that mixed content, due to my invalid security certificate` - no, mixed content in a web page is a problem when a page loaded using `https` tries to load a resource (css, js, etc) using `http` ...

Comment: mixed content come due to application hardcode the path in-to the content, which wouldn't be replaced by nginx. To fix that, you can instruct nginx to rewrite the content or you could fix the application to properly generate links or use relative ones.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the certificate is self signed. If you sign the certicate (eg using somethings like certbot) the ssl indicator on browser become green